# Lightning Component force:input populate WhoId on Task Object

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to pre-populate the WhoId for a force:inputField field .  I have the pre-poluation working for the WhatId but not the WhoId.  The WhoId does not have "v.values" field.  Is there a way to do this?

```
 <div>
            <label>Related To</label>
            <force:inputField aura:id="whatId" value="{!v.newTask.WhatId}" />
        </div> 
        <div class="whoId-field">
            <label>Name</label>
            <force:inputField aura:id="thewhoId" value="{!v.newTask.WhoId}" />
        </div>

values = [{
                type: 'Account',
                id:  '0016E000003vp1NQAQ',
                label:  'ABC Company',
                icon: {
                    url: '/img/icon/t4v35/standard/account_120.png',
                    backgroundColor: 'A094ED',
                    alt: 'Contact'
                }
            }];
            cmp.find('whatId').get("v.body")[0].set('v.values', values);
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same issue. If you manually set a contact in this field from the UI, then view the contents of the WhoId field, it will look something like this:
[{"id":"003xxxxxxxxxxxxx","context":{"jidListName":"nullWhoIds"}}] So I try to pass the same to my WhoId, but it didn't work.
My guess is this has something to do with the ability to relate multiple contacts to a task. I did notice that if I run my component instead as an application, it works (it also only supports 1 contact).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue using the below code.

```
if (userObj.hasOwnProperty('WhoId')) {
                var value = [{
                    type: userObj.WhoType,
                    id: userObj.WhoId,
                    label: userObj.WhoName,
                    icon: {
                        url: '/img/icon/t4v35/standard/contact_120.png',
                        backgroundColor: 'A094ED',
                        alt: 'Contact'
                    }
                }];
                cmp.set('v.newTask.WhoId', "[{\"id\":\"" + userObj.WhoId + "\",\"context\":{\"jidListName\":\"nullWhoIds\"}}]");
                var values = [];
                values.push(value);

                var parent = cmp.find('thewhoId');  //the aura-id of the field

                if (parent === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                var e = parent.getElements()[0];

                if (e === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                var globalId = e.getAttribute('data-aura-rendered-by');
                var a = $A.getComponent(globalId);
                var vp = a.getAttributeValueProvider();

                vp.set('v.values', value);
            }
```